# Cannot open TUN/TAP, openVPN issues

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, tunneling

I have openVPN, and the vm runs fine otherwise. It can connect to the internet, and run localhosts, and all sorts of things. I need access to a vpn through it though. I have my ovpn file, and my username / password. However, after running openvpn --config [name of ovpn file], and then after entering my username and password I get this error message:

```
Sat May 13 09:59:18 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Sat May 13 09:59:18 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sat May 13 09:59:18 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Sat May 13 09:59:18 2017 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=enp0s3 HWADDR=08:00:27:89:26:b8
Sat May 13 09:59:18 2017 ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev Ethernet 2: No such file or directory (errno=2)
Sat May 13 09:59:18 2017 Exiting due to fatal error
```

My question is: what does this error message mean, and how do I solve it?  Below is my ovpn file:

```
remote **.**.**.****
resolv-retry infinite
explicit-exit-notify
nobind
ca ca.crt
cert **.crt
key **.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher  AES-128-CBC
ns-cert-type server
verb 3
comp-lzo
auth-user-pass
auth-retry interact
dev-node "Ethernet 2"
```

Comment: Possible misconfiguration: Somewhere there's the string "Ethernet 2" instead of the name of the tun/tap interface. Can you share the contents of the ovpn file (without sensitive information)?

Comment: You're right!  That is in my ovpn file.  Any idea what it should be changed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the line with

```
dev-node "Ethernet 2"
```

in the opvn file with

```
dev tun
```

Explanation: `dev-node` gives the explicit path, but OpenVPN should be able to figure out the right path for your system. It just needs to know whether to create `tun` or `tap` device, and for that, the `dev` option is sufficient. Numbering should also happen automatically.